# Non-ASCII filenames are being broken in Jira on Debian

Tags: debian, encoding, jira

I have an old Jira 3.12 installed on Linux (Debian, 6.0.4). The encoding in OS is setup to UTF-8.

My problem: if somebody adds an attachment with non-ASCII symbols in its filename, it is created correctly - correct record in the database and a correct filename in the file system.  But after various time, some filenames are being broken - non-ASCII characters are replaced by ‘?’ symbols, but the “Date of change” attribute is not updated, and changes are not made to database.

What can be the reason of such problem?

Comment: How sure are you that the filenames have actually changed? Maybe your method of displaying then sometimes struggles with non-ASCII characters? E.g. redirect a dir listing into a file `ls > list.txt` and view that with a UTF8-aware editor

Comment: Thank you, I have checked: 48248_????? ??????? ????????? 3 ??????? NR.png. The filenames are realy broken

Comment: How have you checked? Make sure you use the --literal option for ls.

Comment: It is sad, but the problem exists on this system. Some non-ASCII filenames are correct, some are broken.